# How to specify typings for dynamic fields similar to django Model/Field?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

For example:

```
# field base class
class F:
    pass


# represent integer
class AF(F):
    pass


# represent string
class BF(F):
    pass


class M:
    a = AF()
    b = BF()

    def __init__(self):
        pass  # generate dynamic attrs based on specified static attrs


m = M()
# m.a should have inferred type integer
```

Maybe it is just IDE (PyCharm) feature with all these type hint, and this feature is hard-bind to django's `Model` class?

Answer (score 0):

Django's Model class has fields that explicitly check the type of the field as well as database migrations to add those types to the DB. If you want to use static types in python, consider using [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) to annotate your functions and variables.

Comment: for static analysis I&#39;m happy with typings+pycharm (don&#39;t know what pycharm uses under the hood). but I wonder if there is a way to dynamically annotate attributes. so far the only way know is to add command with type, eg `#  type: str`

Comment: If you're using Python 3.6, you can use the following annotations: `x:int` or `x:str` or `x:Union[int, str]` as seen here: http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html and PyCharm will recognize them